# Классификация и обработка результата плавающего типа в Java

Tags: java, проектирование, оформление, discord-jda

Пишу бота для Discord на JDA. Хочу всё структурировать, классифицировать по красоте, читаемости и расширяемости с учётом принятых в Java стандартов оформления кода (в которых мало что понимаю, поэтому и задаю этот вопрос).

[image: Схема структуры программы, псевдокод]

```
public class Bot {

    private Commands activeCommands;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // ...

        Bot bot = new Bot(token);
    }

    public Bot(String token) {

        activeCommands = new Commands();
        activeCommands.add(new HelpCommand());
        activeCommands.add(new PingCommand());
        activeCommands.add(new DiceCommand());
        activeCommands.add(new BlackJackCommand());
        // etc...

        JDA jda = new JDABuilder(token)
            .addEventListeners(new BotListenerAdapter(activeCommands))
            .build();
    }
}

public class Commands extends HashSet<Command> {
    // ...
}

public abstract class Command {

    protected Set<String> aliases;

    public Command(String name) {
        this.aliases = new HashSet<>();
        this.aliases.add(name);
    }

    public Command(String[] aliases) {
        this.aliases = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(aliases));
    }

    abstract protected ??? action(String[] params);
}

public class BotListenerAdapter extends ListenerAdapter {

    private Commands activeCommands;

    public BotListenerAdapter(Commands cmds) {
        activeCommands = cmds;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@Nonnull MessageReceivedEvent event) {

        Message msg = event.getMessage();
        MessageChannel channel = msg.getChannel();
        String content = msg.getContentRaw();

        // кусок кода, проверяющий, является ли content командой
        // и разделяющий его на commandName и commandParams

        Command cmd = activeCommands.find(commandName);
        ??? result = cmd.action(commandParams);

        // далее делаем что-то с результатом, в зависимости от его
        // типа и отправляем ответ через
        channel.sendMessage(...);
        // или
        channel.sendFile(...);
        // или ещё что-то, опять же, в зависимости от типа
    }
}
```

У меня есть главный класс `Bot`, в котором объявлено поле `private Commands activeCommands`, оно передаётся объекту класса `BotListenerAdapter extends net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter`, который передаётся JDABuilder'у при создании объекта JDA. `Commands` — это просто обёрточка над `HashSet<Command>` с дополнительным функционалом для быстрого поиска нужной команды и всяким таким. `Command` — это абстрактный класс, от которого наследуются разные команды и реализуют соответствующую логику.

По задумке `BotListenerAdapter` обрабатывает получение сообщения в канале через переопределение метода `onMessageReceived`, проверяет наличие команды в `activeCommands` и вызывает у неё метод `action` (тот самый абстрактный метод с логикой), передавая параметры команды, после чего метод `action` отрабатывает и возвращает некий результат, который там же в обработчике `onMessageReceived` бот должен отправить ответом в канал дискорда в том или ином формате. Ну, чтобы не передавать в объект команды всякую муть, вроде объектов канала, отправителя и т.д. Команда отработала автономно, а ответом занимается уже `BotListenerAdapter`, получив её результат.

Проблема вот в чём: результат исполнения команды может быть разный. Это может быть как plain-text-ответ или Discord Embed или какая-нибудь гифка, так и более сложная конструкция, напичканная всякими фьючерами (или потоками, пока не знаю, пишу «сверху-вниз»), представляющая из себя Embed с функциональными кнопками, реализованными через reactions дискорда. Естественно, разные виды результата и обрабатывать нужно по-разному и представлять пользователю в разном формате и разными способами. Как быть в таком случае? Каким образом лучше всего будет классифицировать результат исполнения `Command.action` и как отличить один вид результата от другого?

Было две идеи. Первая:

Написать `inferface CommandResult` с методом `process`, принимающим в качестве параметров всё, что может понадобиться для обработки результата, в т.ч. объекты канала, пользователя, отправившего команду, список активных в текущий момент игр (бот игровой), контекст базы данных и прочее-прочее, и реализовывать через него разные подклассы результатов. Совсем не кажется хорошим решением, т.к. тащить всю эту вереницу ссылок на глубокие уровни не хочется. Тем более, дальнейшая расширяемость от этого явно пострадает, ведь Бог его знает, какой ещё функционал потребуется добавить. Слишком много придётся дописывать и переписывать.

И вторая идея — написать `enum CommandResult` с несколькими константами, определяющими разные виды результатов и эксклюзивными данными и методами для разных констант, но... как-то слегка отдаёт это костылём. Может я ошибаюсь, но есть ощущение, будто бы перечисления в Java для этого никто не использует и должен быть более элегантный подход.

И так, вопросы:

1. Допустима ли вообще описанная мной структура приложения в Java? Если нет, то что именно в ней плохо? Понятно, что писать можно, как угодно, лишь бы работало, но есть же какие-то негласные стандарты. На одном языке принято делать так, на другом сяк. Я не слишком опытен в Java. Работал с ней немного, когда учился в универе, кое-что понимаю, но это мой первый относительно серьёзный проект на ней.
2. Приемлем ли какой-то из двух описанных мной вариантов решения данной проблемы? Если да, то какой? Я вполне могу ошибаться по поводу `enum` и, возможно, это действительно хороший вариант, но мне интересно мнение опытного Java-программиста.
3. Если оба предложенных мной варианта действительно неприемлемы, то как лучше сделать? Как бы сделали Вы?

Comment: `talk is cheap, show me the code`. Зачем писать простыню текста, если можно показать код?

Comment: @tym32167 Потому что бОльшая часть кода всё ещё у меня в голове. По имеющимся обрывком понять конкретику моего вопроса было бы сложнее, поэтому я её подробно описал на естественном языке. Говорю же, пишу сверху-вниз. Не люблю переписывать по 350 раз, поэтому то, в чём не уверен, вообще пока в коде не описано. Это вопрос больше по проектированию

Comment: вы просто поймите, что такое количество текста мало кто будет читать. Если у вас кода нет, ну нарисуйте в паинте UML схему или что то типа того, чтобы разбавить текст и чтобы суть была более ясна.

Comment: @tym32167 Понимаю. Спасибо за замечание. Про схему как-то сразу не подумал, т.к. сам достаточно легко воспринимаю текст без схем. Дополнил. Теперь лучше?

Comment: А говорите, у вас коде нет. Вот же он, на картинке. Вставьте его текстом. Ничего страшного, что он не компилируется, зато по нему сразу понятна ваша проблема.

Comment: @tym32167 Так его действительно нет. Это же вообще не код, а псевдокод. Я его сейчас на картинке писал из головы, а не копировал из редактора. Поэтому не относящиеся к вопросу куски вообще заменил комментариями...
Но... ладно, если это принципиально, напишу ещё и текстом.

Comment: @tym32167 По-моему, теперь вопрос выглядит ещё более громоздким и отпугивающим... Неужели людям, читавшим книги по программированию, 6 коротеньких абзацев прочитать лень?

Comment: одно дело читать книги для себя и другое дело бесплатно помогать. Здесь так много вопросов низкого качества, что я, например, трачу обычно на вопрос 10 секунд и если я не понял суть вопроса за это время, то просто его пропускаю. В вашем случае, вы показали, что вам не все равно и вам действительно нужен ответ, потому я посвятил вам больше времени. Но вообще рутина отвечающих тут - это отбиваться от одних людей, что просят делать работу за них и просить других юзеров повысить качество их вопросов - это то, на что отвечающие тут тратят 90% времени.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Java допустима любая архитектура, которая компилируется. Нет каких то специфичных для Java особых архитектур.

Вопрос номер раз: зачем их команды что то возвращать? Не может ли сама команда печатать вывод куда надо? Смотрим [паттерн команда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Пример команды:

```
abstract class Command {
    public abstract boolean canExecute(Object obj);
    public abstract void execute(Object obj);
}

class CurrentTimeCommand extends Command {

    private final PrintStream printStream;

    public CurrentTimeCommand(PrintStream printStream){
        this.printStream = printStream;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canExecute(Object obj) {
        return  ("timenow".equals(obj));
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Object obj) {
        this.printStream.println("Time is " + LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

Использование

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Command> commands = new ArrayList<>();
    commands.add(new CurrentTimeCommand(System.out));

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputText = scanner.nextLine();

    commands.stream().filter(cmd->cmd.canExecute(inputText)).forEach(cmd->cmd.execute(inputText));
}
```

---

Другой вариант называется [цепочка обязанностей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9)

Суть в том, что можно передавать один и тот же мессадж командам. Например, вот у нас есть наша базовая команда

```
abstract class Command {
    public abstract boolean canExecute(Object obj);
    public abstract void execute(Object obj);
}
```

Но в этот раз у нас есть еще и обработчик

```
class CommandHandler {
    ArrayList<Command> commands = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addCommand(Command command) {
        commands.add(command);
    }

    public <T> void handle(T input) {
        commands.stream().filter(cmd -> cmd.canExecute(input)).forEach(cmd -> cmd.execute(input));
    }
}
```

Сделаем отдельную команду на вывод в печать, вот её входной параметр

```
class PrintInput {
    private final String content;

    public PrintInput(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

Сама команда

```
class PrintCommand extends Command {

    private final PrintStream printStream;

    public PrintCommand(PrintStream printStream) {
        this.printStream = printStream;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canExecute(Object obj) {
        return obj.getClass().equals(PrintInput.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Object obj) {
        PrintInput input = (PrintInput) obj;
        this.printStream.println(input.getContent());
    }
}
```

Тогда наша команда с текущим временем будет такая

```
class CurrentTimeCommand extends Command {

    private final CommandHandler commandHandler;

    public CurrentTimeCommand(CommandHandler commandHandler) {
        this.commandHandler = commandHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canExecute(Object obj) {
        return ("timenow".equals(obj));
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Object obj) {
        String payload = "Time is " + LocalDateTime.now();
        commandHandler.handle(new PrintInput(payload));
    }
}
```

Соберем все вместе

```
    CommandHandler commandHandler = new CommandHandler();
    commandHandler.addCommand(new CurrentTimeCommand(commandHandler));
    commandHandler.addCommand(new PrintCommand(System.out));

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputText = scanner.nextLine();

    commandHandler.handle(inputText);
```

Как видите, в примере выше одна команда передала сообщение другой команде, при этом сами команды никак не связаны между собой. Таким способом вы можете строить любые цепочки какие вам понравятся.

---

Если развивать тему дальше, то можно уйти совсем в дебри и вспоминить Бертрана Майера, который предлагал все методы делить на команды и запросы ([CQRS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CQRS), [Фаулер](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)), но это уже ближе к теме микросервисов и DDD.

Comment: Почему команда не может сама печатать вывод? Потому что я хочу отделить генерацию результата от его отправки через JDA. И потому что помимо его отправки могут требоваться ещё какие-то действия: добавить/удалить данные из БД, запустить ещё какие-то отдельные процессы. Например, сейчас в планах добавить многоэтапные игры, которые могут исполняться параллельно с разными пользователями. Информацию о текущих играх и их состояниях нужно где-то хранить и учитывать. Команда, как минимум, генерирует информацию об играх и должна добавить её в HashSet<Game>.

Comment: А если мне приспичит добавить ещё какую-то механику? Вы представляете, сколько ссылок придётся передавать в КАЖДЫЙ объект Command, несмотря на то, что далеко не каждый из них будет с ними всеми работать? Мне кажется, лучше отделить генерацию результата от действий, которые потом будут с этим результатом выполняться, в т.ч. его отправки. Это как MVC. Логика отдельно от представления.

Comment: Даже для самой отправки ответа нужен объект channel. Чтобы в ответе обратиться к пользователю, отправившему команду, и у него высветилось уведомление, нужен объект user. Это уже две ссылки, которые придётся тащить в объект команды, а ведь они, по большому счёту, к логике исполнения команды малое отношение имеют. И получается, что мы множим эти ссылки в огромных количествах, передавая их в каждую команду. Зачем всё это? Это уже какой-то небольшой ссылочный ад получается. А там ещё много таких ссылок.

Comment: `Вы представляете, сколько ссылок придётся передавать в КАЖДЫЙ объект Command` в команду можно передавать только те ссылки, что команде нужны. Если команде надо писать в channel - передавате ссылку туда, если не надо - не передавайте. Каждая команда вообще получилась изолирована от других ссылок / команд. Я ес честно, просто не понял ваших проблем с моим ответом. Можете привести пример кода с лишними ссылками?

Comment: Я вообще не вижу проблем ни с запуском игровой логики, ни с работой с БД. Если вам надо писать в БД в команде - передайте ей ваш репозиторий в конструкторе и данные на вход и вперед. Реализация игры - это отдельная система, но триггерить логику этой системы можно также командами, какие тут проблемы?

Comment: Взгляните на метод `BotListenerAdapter.onMessageReceived` в моём псевдокоде: `Command cmd = activeCommands.find(commandName);` `Command` — это абстрактный класс. Нам неизвестно, какому конкретно его подклассу принадлежит выбранная пользователем команда. Мы вызываем абстрактный метод `action`, общий для всех реализацией, обладающий общим для всех реализацией набором параметров.

Comment: Взгляните на `abstract class Command` в моем ответе. Это тоже абстрактный класс. И мы также не знаем, что конкретно вызываем в классе `CommandHandler`. В чем проблема то?

Comment: Я вам даже код в такой манере написал, что вы можете просто взять команду и тестировать её, без участия других команд. Команды тут никак не связаны. Сообщение между камандами происходит через посредника. Потому одна команда может росчиывать факториалы, а вторая играть в mmorpg и никаких лишних зависимостей нигде не будет.

Comment: В том, что Вы предлагаете передавать нужные ссылки (например, ссылку на System.out) в команды на этапе их создания. Т.е. каждая команда у вас априори работает на заранее определённые ресурсы. В моём же случае команды приходят от разных пользователей на разных каналах, и отвечать им нужно в эти каналы с использованием их юзернейма в качестве обращения, т.е. эти данные придётся передавать не в конструктор, а в `.execute()`, у которого должна быть общая для всех команд структура.

Comment: Есть ещё один момент. ВОЗМОЖНО, я хочу в дальнейшем предоставить пользователям возможность расширять функционал бота и вводить собственные команды, но при этом хочу ограничить их свободу стандартными правилами (одна команда — ровно один ответ, в одном из описанных мной форматов). Т.е. я не хочу давать им возможность напрямую взаимодействовать с объектами JDA, а только описать свою логику исполнения команд.

Comment: @ tym32167 паттерн команда настоятельно не рекомендуется показывать людям, начинающим изучать ООП, потому как он это самое ООП ломает, а потом те, кто его освоил на ранних этапах обучения, начинают все писать с его помощью. а вот цепочка обязанностей, как мне кажется, вполне подойдет и никакого неправильного "осадка" не оставит. ответ хороший, однозначно голосую за

Comment: `В моём же случае команды приходят от разных пользователей на разных каналах` так сделайте отдельный класс для хранения каналов пользователей. Такой класс можно передавать в конструктор команд. При закрытии канала убирайте его реестра класса, при открытии нового - добавляйте в реестр.

Comment: `Есть ещё один момент. ВОЗМОЖНО, я хочу в дальнейшем предоставить пользователям возможность расширять функционал бота и вводить собственные команды` это ответсвенность классов, которые будут создавать и конфигурировать подобные команды. Это никак не влияет на предложенную мной архитектуру @lem0nify

Comment: @Дмитрий если вы присмотритесь к коду, увидите, что реализация цепочки обязанностей у меня не стардартная, а также через команды :)

Comment: Как же это не влияет? Если дать юзеру возможность наследовать свои классы от Command и прописывать там логику, а среди этой логики должна быть и, непосредственно, отправка ответа, то пользователю нужно и интерфейс для этой самой отправки ответа предоставить. И если это будет интерфейс в виде вызова метода, то что помешает ему вызвать его дважды, трижды, форматировать ответ так, как ему хочется? Другое дело, когда ему, по моей изначально предложенной архитектуре, придётся вернуть из команды один единственный результат исполнения по чёткому образцу (или одному из).

Comment: @lem0nify `Если дать юзеру возможность наследовать свои классы от Command` юзер не может наследовать какой либо класс из вашего кода. Все, что может юзер - это как то сконфигурировать какие то команды по правилам, которые вы пропишете. Причем эти правила никак не связаны с архитектурой чего либо, это сугубо правила, которые определяют, что юзер может делать и чего не может делать.

Comment: @lem0nify вы сейчас придумываете какие то абстракнтные проблемы и добавляете к своему вопросу какие то вымышленные подробности. Вы четко обозначили проблему в своем вопросе - вам непонятно, как обработать результат команды. Я вам показал, что вместо обработки результата команды, можно выполнить другую команду. И я не очень понимаю, как ваши новые претензии к моему ответу коррелируют с вашим изначальным вопросом. У меня возникает ощущение, что вы сами не понимаете, какую проблему вы хотите решить.

Comment: Так ведь в своём вопросе я также достаточно чётко обозначил, что я не хочу тащить кучу ссылок на ресурсы на более глубокие уровни классовой архитектуры, разве нет? А Вы предлагаете совершенно другое решение, противоречащее этой установке, пытаясь объяснить мне, что она бессмысленна. Я же, в свою очередь, это оспариваю, дополняя проблему «вымышленными подробностями», которые объясняют, почему я нахожу эту установку НЕ бессмысленной.

Comment: Мне нужно что-то в духе классических web MVC-фреймворков. Пользователь может описать свой контроллер со своими путями маршрутизации и вернуть из каждого некий Result, который может быть как объектом, который, например, десериализуется в JSON, так и строкой с HTML-кодом, так и, например, FileStream'ом, который отправляется в ответе. Нужно что-то подобное. Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как это реализуется в Java. Я пытался ковырять код Spring, но там всё на каких-то сложных многоуровневых аннотациях, в которых я не могу разобраться. Но наверняка же есть более простой путь.

Comment: @lem0nify так в MVC у вас будет ровно то же самое. Представления у вас не будет в принципе (у вас же бот, какие там представления), модели будут входной информацией для контроллера, а контроллер будет 1-1 эквивалент команды. Вам точно также придется передавать каналы связи, юзера и другие зависимости в  контроллер.

Comment: Ну вообще-то ответы бота тоже можно оформить как представления. Ну да ладно, чёрт с ним. Спасибо за конструктивный диалог. Буду думать.